# wget with bash command and save to other folder

Tags: bash, terminal, wget

I am downloading bulk images from with bash command and here is my sample file list.sh

```
wget    https://www.japanesebuyers.com/jct/vehicle_image/2223787_a.jpg -O image1.jpg
wget    https://www.japanesebuyers.com/jct/vehicle_image/1_15450940845c1843c49b959.jpeg -O  image2.jpg
```

when I run this command in terminal ./list.sh it download file in the same folder.
I want to save files in /images/ folder

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell the `wget` command you want to download your images in the images folder. The `-O` is the output. If you add `-O ./images/image1.jpg` it should work.
Alternatively, if you don't want to add the folder in each command, you can `cd` in the appropriate folder with `cd images` before calling `wget`.